# QuickFix/N sending repeated logons

Tags: quickfix

I use QuickFixN to connect to 2 liquidity providers.
One is connecting and working fine. The other isn't showing any error message, seems to be connecting, but Logon isn't succeeding.

In the messages log: I am sending the Logon request (message type 'A'), and receiving back another message type A, but then nothing happens. 30secs later this happens again. It has many repeats looking like this:

```
20131118-20:11:32.422 : 8=FIX.4.49=11535=A34=149=XXXX50=XXXX52=20131118-20:11:32.40856=XXXX57=XXXX98=0108=30141=Y10=152
20131118-20:11:32.795 : 8=FIX.4.49=11535=A34=149=XXXX50=XXXX52=20131118-20:11:32.61956=XXXX57=XXXX98=0108=30141=Y10=156
....same again every 30secs....
```

the event log looks like this:

```
20131118-20:11:32.023 : Connecting to AA.AAA.AAA.AAA on port BBBB
20131118-20:11:32.395 : Connection succeeded
20131118-20:11:32.408 : Session reset: ResetOnLogon
20131118-20:11:32.422 : Session reset: ResetSeqNumFlag
20131118-20:11:32.422 : Initiated logon request
20131118-20:11:32.796 : Message 1 Rejected: 9
20131118-20:11:32.798 : Verify failed: Tried to send a reject while not logged on
20131118-20:11:32.798 : Session FIX.4.4:XXXX->YYYY disconnecting: Verify failed: Tried to send a reject while not logged on
```

Within my application, on the QuickFix.Application interface, OnCreate is being called for this session, and so is OnLogout, but OnLogon is not. Neither FromAdmin or FromApp receive any messages from this session.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I know you said your message log doesn't have much in it, but can you show it anyway for the time period corresponding to this event log?

Comment: I've updated the question to include it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Message 1 Rejected: 9" phrase is saying the message with sequence number 1 (the Logon message) was rejected for reason 9. The reason is a FIX Session Reject Reason and 9 indicates a CompID problem. Double-check your sender and target CompIDs in the message to be sure they are correct for your counterparty. Note that your side of the session is rejecting their login so it could be an issue with configuration of your session. The "Verify failed" message is logged because QuickFIX/n is apparently trying to send a reject message before the session is logged in.

Comment: thanks - but how did you know that reason 9 is a CompID problem?

Comment: Ah, he nailed it.  Your app is trying to send a Reject (35=3) for their login message, but it fails to send because the connection is terminated.  The "9" is actually the value of field 373 (SessionRejectReason).  See the [message definition for Reject](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/body_5251.html).

Comment: @mcmillab I looked at the source code and saw that the number was for the SessionRejectReason. :-)